# Assigment of a value to a var in bash shell script failed

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to assign a value to a var in an if statement but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
if [ -z $var ]
then 
   $var=210
fi
```

It's showing me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `var=210`, without `$`.

`$var` retrieves the value (and [then you want to double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)).

Another common mistake is to put space(s) next to `=` (e.g. `var = 210`, wrong); your code doesn't suffer from this one though.

---

To assign `210` when the variable `var` is empty or unset, use this syntax:

```
var="${var:-210}"
```

This single command does what your entire `if …` snippet was supposed to do. There are few similar yet different syntaxes, see a table [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).